# How many liters of water remain in the first urn after 1977th pouring? (Full Question in description)

Tags: recursive-algorithms

One urn contains 1 liter of water, while a second urn is empty. after 1/2 of the water in the first urn is emptied into the second urn, 1/3 of the water in the second urn is returned to the first urn. Then, 1/4 of the contents of the first urn is poured into the second urn, followed by the return of 1/5 of the contents of the second urn. At each successive pouring from alternate urns, the denominator of the fractional part poured increases by 1. How many liters of water remain in the first urn after 1977th pouring? (Please be specific as to how you come up with each step, thank you)

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried first. For example, have you tried figuring out how much water is in the urn after 1/3 of the water in the second urn is returned? Try making a list of how much water is in the urn at each step.

Comment: @rogerl this is what I have found out so far:

Comment: FIRST URN  SECOND EARN
½    1/2
5/6    1/6
¼   5/12
9/20   13/60

Comment: @Daniel it works better if you edit the post with your results rather than put them in a comment. Also format them in a way that's easy to read - maybe two turns per line. And double check your arithmetic

Comment: In addition to adding to your post and writing in the form of a table, you might find it clearer if instead of writing the contents of the first urn as a fraction you write it as a sum: for example, after the 1/3 step, the amount in the first urn is $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}$ (that is in fact $\frac{5}{6}$, as you computed, but if you continue to write as a sum you may find the answer easier to understand).

Comment: @rogerl wow... i understand your point. The answer below is in table form and I can easily understand what he is trying to demonstrate. Lesson learned and thank you.

Comment: @rogerl `after the 1/3 step` The amount after the first step is actually $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{3}\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{Pouring #} & \text{Amount poured} & \text{Into Urn} & \text{Urn 1 before} & \text{Urn 2 before} & \text{Urn 1 after} & \text{Urn 2 after}\\ \hline
\text{0} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{1} & 1/2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\text{2} & 1/3 & 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 1/4 & 2 & 2/3 & 1/3 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 1/5 & 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 3/5 & 2/5 \\ \hline
\text{5} & 1/6 & 2 & 3/5 & 2/5 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\text{6} & 1/7 & 1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 4/7 & 3/7 \\ \hline
\text{7} & 1/8 & 2 & 4/7 & 3/7 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\text{...} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We can note that for all odd pouring number $n \ge 1$, the "after" is perfectly even - $1/2$ to $1/2$ - and that for all even pouring number $n \ge 2$, the "after" is $\frac{n+2}{2n+2}$ to $\frac{n}{2n+2}$. This means that for pouring number $n = 1976$, where $1/1977$ of the contents from urn 2 will be poured to urn 1, the contents in urn 1 will be $$\fbox{(1976+2)/(2*1976+2) = 989/1977}$$

Comment: Ohhhh i finally got it thank you.

Comment: I think @dxiv made a correct point. The problem states: $1/3$ of the water in the second urn is returned", which means $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ resulting in $2/3$, not $5/6$.

Comment: @2012ssohn I was reviewing the problem and was wondering where the n+2/ 2n+2 came from because the problem stated for each successive pouring the denominator increased by 1. The table helped me figure out the answer but I am just confused as to where the formula came from or what the variables stand for.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little clearer. First note that, if you're pouring away $1/n$ of an urn's contents into the other urn, you're effectively **keeping** $(n-1)/n$ of it in the original urn and then putting the rest in the other urn. So for pouring #2, because we're pouring away $1/3$ of urn 2 (which had $1/2$), we're **keeping** $2/3$ of that $1/2$, so $2/3*1/2 = 1/3$. Similarly for pouring #3, we pour away $1/4$ of urn 3 (which had $2/3$), so we're **keeping** $3/4$ of $2/3$, or $3/4*2/3 = 2/4 = 1/2$.

Comment: After that, the key is to look at the content of urn 1 for even numbered pourings (since it seems to be $1/2$ for all odd numbered pourings). We note that when $n = 2,4,6,\cdots$, we get $urn1 = 2/3,3/5,4/7,\cdots$. We note that all the denominators are $n+1$, and the numerators are all half the denominator plus $1/2$. In other words, the fraction is $(1/2(n+1)+1/2)/(n+1)$, or $((n+1)+1)/(2n+2) = (n+2)/(2n+2)$.

Comment: @2012ssohn so does "n" stand for the liters of water or the pouring number

Comment: Pouring number.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,a_n\,$ be the liters of water in the first urn after $\,n\,$ pourings. Since the total amount of water is constant, the liters in the second urn after $\,n\,$ pourings will be $\,1-a_n\,$.

The initial condition is $\,a_0=1\,$, and the rules of pouring give the following recursive relations:

$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n-1} &= a_{2n-2} - \frac{1}{2n}a_{2n-2} = \frac{2n-1}{2n}a_{2n-2} \tag{1} \\[5px]
a_{2n} &= a_{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}(1 -a_{2n-1}) = \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{2n}{2n+1}a_{2n-1} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Writing $\,(1)\,$ for $\,2n+1\,$ and using $\,(2)\,$:

$$
a_{2n+1} = \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}a_{2n} = \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{2n}{2n+1}a_{2n-1}\right) = \frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{2n}{2n+2}a_{2n-1} \tag{3}
$$

Relation $\,(3)\,$ implies that if $\require{cancel}\,a_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{2}\,$ then $\,a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{\bcancel{2}n}{2n+2}\frac{1}{\bcancel{2}}=\frac{n+1}{2n+2}=\frac{1}{2}\,$ and, since $\,a_1=\frac{1}{2}\,$, it follows by induction that all odd-index $\,a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\,$. Therefore $\,a_{1977}=\frac{1}{2}\,$.